# Not able to change bootstrap modal css in project?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

As, I have used a `bootstrap` `modal-dialog` in my project and I want to change the `css` of that `modal-dialog` but I am not able to change it. I tried for the top of the `modal-dialog` and not able to see any result.
Below is my `html` code:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-container" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Edit Your Detail</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <small>Purpose</small>
                    <input type="text" name="NPurpose" id="IPurpose" class="form-control" placeholder="Purpose" tabindex="2">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <small>DOP</small>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="IDop" name="NDop" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"  tabindex="3">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <small>Unit Price</small>
                    <input type="text" name="NUp" id="IUp" class="form-control" placeholder="Unit Price" data-bv-stringlength-max="1" tabindex="4">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <small>Quantity</small>
                    <input type="text" name="NQty" id="IQty" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" tabindex="5">
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <small>Description</small>
                    <textarea  name="NDescp" id="IDescp" class="form-control" maxlength="200" rows="4" placeholder="Description" tabindex="6"></textarea>
                    <span id="chars">200</span> characters remaining
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="width: 100%;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
                                                    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
</div>
```

and here is my `css` code:

```
.modal-dialog{ 

    top:50% !important;
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

Comment: are you importing CSS correctly? check your console.., your code is absoultely fine https://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1490/

Comment: can you show us live view of your project ?

Comment: Make a fiddle/snippet so everyone can look into it, before that do you care to look your console first? it will tell you something.

Comment: hi, Yaar I am working with PHP since 2008 and I have developed many projects. But its a quiet strange thing that its working now without modifying any code. I think the data might be updated and the file was not taking by the xamp server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show modal in **center** & **middle** of screen then try this code. I hope this help you.

```
.modal-dialog {
 position: fixed;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: No success. its on same position

Comment: I think **bootstrap.min.css** file is bottom of your **custom style** file so please make sure **bootstrap.min.css** file should be on top of your **custome style** file. after that your css property will work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you put your custom css after Bootstrap css in your head tag, its look like below code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to-bootstrap-css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to-your-custom-css.css">
```

Now come to your problem

if you want to change all modal design in your website then use class same as you use but write below css in your custom css file also don't need to add **!important**

```
.modal-dialog{ 

    top:50%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

if you want to change design for particular single modal then use id for design your modal

ex. you use id "**edit**" then your css looks like below

```
#edit .modal-dialog{ 
    top:50%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

You don't need to add **!important**.